# Subdomain pointing to AWS amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, hosting, aws-amplify, cname

I have a domain ([www.aaa.com](http://www.aaa.com)) from a platform, a hosting service from another platform (a Wordpress web page is running here) and I've deployed my app to AWS. What I want to do is to create a subdomain ([www.bb.aaa.com](http://www.bb.aaa.com)) that points to the app in AWS. First I created the subdomain in hosting service and from Zone editor I assigned CNAME value to the value that I got from AWS Amplify. But it didn't work (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error). What is wrong/missing in this flow?

Answer (score 0):

AS you did not mention configuring your `Amplify` application for the domain. I am assuming you are missing DNS configuration part in the AWS Console for `Amplify` app.

That's why you receiving the error `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

> This means that your DNS server successfully received a response from an upstream source stating that the record did not exist, and not due to a communication problem

This is a step by step guide for adding the DNS records when you deal with a third-party DNS provider [Add a custom domain managed by a third-party DNS provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-a-third-party-dns-provider.html)

The most important part is where you configure your `Amplify` app for your domain and adding the corresponding entries where you have hosted your zone. Below is a screenshot of similar records from the documentation page I linked.

[image]

[Troubleshooting custom domains](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/custom-domain-troubleshoot-guide.html)